# Getting empty result sets from MySQL Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL stored procedure that returns multiple result sets. See below

```
` BEGIN                                                                  /**/

        SELECT  u.user_id,
                u.user_name
        FROM    user u
        UNION
        SELECT 1,1 FROM DUAL WHERE FALSE;

        SELECT  g.group_id,
                g.group_name
        FROM    group g
        UNION
        SELECT 1,1 FROM DUAL WHERE FALSE;

        SELECT  r.role_id,
                r.role_name
        FROM    role r
        UNION
        SELECT 1,1 FROM DUAL WHERE FALSE;

    END`
```

Within PHP, I count the resultset being processed in the below manner

```
   $rsCount = 1;
        do {
            $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($rowset) {
                switch ($rsCount) {
                    case 1: //first resultset
                        $users = $rowset;
                        break;
                    case 2: //second resulset 
                        $groups = $rowset;
                        break;
                    case 3: //third resultset
                        $roles = $rowset;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            $rsCount++;
        } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

However if the group table is empty then MySQL only returns 2 resultsets and it throws my PHP logic - is there anyway to force MySQL to return an empty resultset? Is there a better PHP logic to process this - for example can I name resultset and check the same in PHP?

Comment: if there isn't a clean way of doing it, you can always `union all` a fixed row onto the query and then ignore it in PHP.

Comment: I am trying this based on other feedback but this is not working as well - `SELECT group_id FROM group UNION SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE FALSE` - is there some where to select 1 based on the number of rows returned by the previous query?

Comment: can you add your stored procedure to the post.

Comment: i have added the stored procedure with the modification mentioned

Comment: Put the fake row first and then always ignore it.

Comment: Can you confirm the RDBMS is MySQL? `dual` smells like Oracle.

Comment: yes the database is MySQL - i believe MySQL also supports DUAL - after all Oracle owns MySQL now

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't know! And this feature existed [long before MySQL was taken over by Oracle](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine a couple of tricks:

- Always add a dummy row, and always ignore the first row:

```
SELECT NULL -- no further condition
UNION ALL
[actual query] ;
```

- `LEFT JOIN` the actual query to the dummy table (but do not select columns from the dummy table). The result set contains one row of `NULL`'s if the actual query has not result:

```
SELECT actualQuery.*
FROM (SELECT NULL) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN ( [actual query] ) AS actualQuery ON TRUE ;
```

If a non-null column (e.g. a primary key) from `[actual query]` is `NULL`, then the row is dummy and the query had no result.